How to add line breaks with openrewrite in java stream api calls?
Assume I have snippet like this
List.of(1, 2, 3)
.stream().map(integer -> integer * integer).filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Want to change it with openrewrite to that
List.of(1, 2, 3)
  .stream()
  .map(integer -> integer * integer)
  .filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());


Line breaks are stored in a prefix attached to every LST element; In this case you will likely want to visit all method invocations, and if their select is itself a method invocation, and the prefix does not already contain a newline, add a newline to the prefix using withPrefix.
You might at the end want to wrap your new method invocation in a maybeAutoFormat(...) method call to get the right level of indentation.
You can see a similar approach being used here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/pull/392
EDIT:
If you want to limit when lines are wrapped, then you can look at the length of the methodInvocation with something like methodInvocation.print().length() > 120.

The answer is complete, but, a hopefully useful observation: Rigidly 'newlining' any method invocation whose receiver is itself a method invocation is likely to add a few more newlines that java programmers are used to. You might just want to be that rigid. Venturing into opinion land: I bet that doesn't help readability. @Tim if you happen to know and are willing to update this answer a slight bit: I'd be intrigued if it is possible to configure openrewrite to add that newline only if, without it, the total line length would exceed some configured max line length.

Fully agree with you there @rzwitserloot; expanded the argument just now to include another hint how to limit the changes made here.

I've tried this realiazation, but it adds new lines before whole expression(I mean List)
@Override
public J.MethodInvocation visitMethodInvocation(J.MethodInvocation methodInvocation, ExecutionContext p) {
  J.MethodInvocation m = super.visitMethodInvocation(methodInvocation, p);
  //myCondition
  m = m.withSelect(
      m.getSelect().withPrefix(Space.format("\n"))
  );
  return m;
}


You'll want to apply that withPrefix to each nested select in the chain, perhaps except for the outer one.

Let me try to be more clear.
It adds prefix just before statement  List.of(1, 2, 3) many times, but not once in stream call. I mean i have something like this as result
--return--
--return--
--return--
--return--
--return--
--return--
List.of(1, 2, 3)
.stream().map(integer -> integer * integer).filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).map(String::valueOf).findAny()

That part was clear; You're applying the prefix repeatedly on the same method invocation it seems, not on each nested select in the chain. Perhaps edit your question to show your updated work, or join our Slack to ask questions there instead of in the comment section here.
